# Is there a preprocessor or something to control what headers visual studio includes?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For example Visual studio includes  `<utility>` even if you didn't explicitly type **`#include <utility>`**

Is there a preprocessor directive or some option to include only what is **explicitly** told by programer?.

Just an hypothetical example:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x;
    std::move(x); // Did I ask for <utility> ? No I didn't
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's not in the precompiled headers section is it? Ie #include "stdafx.h" or similar?

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't automatically include anything. It must be coming from another header you're including.

Comment: @Preet, no it's not :)  I've included **<map>** and **<vector>** but **std::sort** and **std::make_pair** are working just fine even if I didn't ask for **<algorithm>** and **<utility>** That's disapointing and goes against the rule of including only what is needed.

Comment: It's a difference between C and C++. In C, standard headers don't include each other, as you prefer. In C++, any standard header is allowed to include any other. They often need to because: (a) templates need to be defined in the header, not just declared, so all their implementation dependencies are needed; (b) there's dependence between types from different headers, stuff like `operator<<(ostream &, const string &)` and (c) implementations historically have been slack about including stuff they strictly could manage without, although I think things have improved more recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual studio doesn't include `<utility>` unless it's required by other included std headers.

In VS10, including only `<vector>` pulls in another 74 headers directly and indirectly.  The trail to `<utility>` is:

`<vector>` includes `<memory>` which includes `<xmemory>` which includes `<xutility>` which includes `<utility>`.

Comment: And even aside from that roundabout route, `vector` in C++11 has a functions that blatantly are going to be implemented using either `std::move` or some implementation-specific clone of it under a different name. `vector::reserve()`, for example, is going to use the multiple-argument overload of `move` in `<algorithm>`, which might well use the single-arg `move` in `<utility>`. The C++ standard *could* forbid `<vector>` to put `move` in namespace `std` in order to do so, thus forcing implementations to use `__move` instead or whatever. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, for your compiler, when you include `vector`, that header also includes something that includes `utility`.

Visual Studio does not automatically include anything and so this is the only explanation for what you describe.

Comment: I'm realy curious if the vector class **it self** really needs something from utility header?

Comment: Will that behaviour of inclusions of std headers be supported on different compilers/IDE's? or should I type #includes manulay to be sure about portability? Thaks.

Comment: Always include all the headers that you need, as detailed in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

When you include `<map>`, it internally uses `std::pair` and so includes `<utility>`. I'm guessing `<vector>` too uses something in `<utility>` if that was the only `#include` you had.